# What is the best way to make unique nodes on neo4j using spring data?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

While working on Neo4j trying to establish unique nodes and relationships for millions of data. Presently we are using Merge query to make uniqueness. Is there any other good approach to make nodes unique?

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. It is hard to help you without seeing code and what isn't working.

Comment: Which version of spring data neo4j?

Comment: @Cody Guldner,

I was trying to insert to the same object multiple times but its inserting all the objects. For me here need a uniqueness if that object is available no need to create any new object. 

Example, Person{Name:abc,age:20} adding 3 times then its inserting 3 rows...As per my requirement supposed to insert only once..

Comment: @Luanne, Neo4j SDN4 we are using in our project..

Answer (score 1):

`MERGE` doesn't prevent to have duplicates, except combined with a uniqueness constraint.

The **ONLY** reliable way of having uniqueness of nodes in the graph is to create a `UNIQUENESS CONSTRAINT`.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (person:Person) ASSERT person.email IS UNIQUE;
```

is how you would create it.

This also create implicitly an index, which makes operations as `MATCH` and `MERGE` an O(1) operation for the matching.